# Raspberry Pi 4 Has Outdated NodeJs and I Can't Update It

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi4

I am using the Raspberry Pi 4 with an SD card that was already set-up with the OS. I tried running my discord bot on it, and while certain commands worked a large majority didn't. I did some looking around and found that NodeJs was already installed and was at v10.21.0 when it should be v14.15.0. I have tried using nvm and other methods to update it but no matter where I look I can't find a reliable way to updat it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From the raspberry-pi4 tag, "PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS ONLY (AND ONLY SPECIFICALLY FOR THIS MODEL) Questions about general use should be asked on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ "

Comment: I would suggest that you detail exactly what you tried to update nodejs and what exactly happened, what errors you saw, etc...?  We can help you better if you give us the actuals methods you tried, actual symptoms and diagnostics of your failure.  For example, were you running with proper elevated privileges when you tried to install?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [NodeSource Ubuntu](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall) distribution of Node.js to install it on a Raspberry Pi. Here are their instructions copied here for convenience:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```